# Swift Error when running Collection view supplementary view in subclass of another custom class

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have a class with populates a collection view, and I need to make another view controller which is similar to this one, but accessible from somewhere else, and with different images, headers, etc. In the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` function, I've made another header type, with purely a label. However, when I try to run it, I get the following crash:

```
2020-06-03 16:50:02.972574+0200 KewbzTrainer Paid[4401:168182] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xe24a9c7456de158f> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (<UICollectionReusableView: 0x7feb1d6d93f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024faa60>>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cc88 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff258b8bd2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48437190 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 747
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4843bf6a -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 7409
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48440cca -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 351
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49193678 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478
    8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4c6398 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    9   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4cc523 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 523
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4d7bba _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
    11  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b420c04 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b4545ef _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 649
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48cb5bdc _afterCACommitHandler + 160
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da0127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9abde __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b12a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9a944 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38ba6c1a GSEventRunModal + 139
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48c8b9ec UIApplicationMain + 1605
    20  KewbzTrainer Paid                   0x000000010bd1982b main + 75
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a231fd start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix it?  Let me know if you need any other of my code samples.

Here is some of the code that I'm having issues with:

```
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            print("A")
            collectionView.register(CLLSectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader")
            if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? CLLSectionHeader {
                print("B")
                switch indexPath.section {
                case 0:
                    print("C")
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel.text = "Sune"
                    print(sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel.text)
                    print("D")
```

As per request, here is my entire code for the supplementary view:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        collectionView.register(CLLSectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader")

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            print("A")
            if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? CLLSectionHeader {
                print("SH \(sectionHeader)")
                print("B")
                switch indexPath.section {
                case 0:
                    print("C")
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "Sune"
                    print(sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text)
                    print("D")
                case 1:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "Antisune"
                case 2:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "Pi"
                case 3:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "U"
                case 4:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "L"
                case 5:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "T"
                case 6:
                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "H"
                default:
                    break
                }
            }

         case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
                   if let sectionFooter = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "OLLSectionFooter", for: indexPath) as? OLLSectionFooter {
                       sectionFooter.alpha = 0.5
                       return sectionFooter
            }
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the `headerFooterView` to the `collectionView`. Like this:

```
collectionView.register(CLLSectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader")
```

Where `CLLSectionHeader` is inherited from `UICollectionReusableView`.

```
class CLLSectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The code goes a bit further, but now crashes on this line `                    sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel.text = "Sune"`.  Says it's nil.  The rest of the code is in the question, for context

Comment: Do optional chaining, `sectionHeader.CLLSectionHeaderLabel?.text = "Sune"`

Comment: Did you register the class you're using?

Comment: Sure I've just added it.

Comment: You're registering inside the header method, move it to `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: even when I register it in VDL, it still crashes with the same error

Comment: Add VDL code too. And test it out first with single type of header view first and then add more conditions.

Comment: If you're using nib your should register using nib method `collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: CLLSectionHeader.nibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "CLLSectionHeader")`